# Use Stack Overflow For API Q&A

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-process

I would like to use Stack Overflow as the Q&A platform for the FamilySearch.org developer API. I've noticed other organizations using Stack Overflow for handling question and answer for their API. Is this an acceptable practice?

I suppose all I would need is a new tag [familysearch-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/familysearch-api) in order to do this. Is this right?

What if I don't have enough reputation to create a new tag?

Comment: Are there already several questions regarding the API on SO? If so, identify them and perhaps a user with sufficient reputation could add the tag.

Comment: This is also answered by the other question marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably a bad idea.

The kinds of questions about APIs that you would want to collect in a FAQ will very often be off topic on Stack Overflow, which has extremely strict on-topicness rules, and a community that is extremely avid in enforcing those rules.

Examples from the [Twitter API FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq):

- **How can I keep up with changes to the Twitter API?** off topic.
- **How do I count out 140 characters?** OK, this may be a valid programming question for SO,  if it's framed right and limited to a specific technology.
- **How do I obtain an API key?** off topic.
- **How do I properly navigate a timeline?** Maybe.
- **How do I use the REST API over JSON-P?** Maybe, but possibly too broad.
- **What does the retirement of API v1 entail?** Likely off topic.
- **How do I use the Twitter platform?** Don't even think about it. Guaranteed to be downvoted into oblivion and closed.

Similar attempts have [failed miserably in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186850/facebook-partnership-and-subsite-no-more), and you don't want to expose the developers using your API to the pain and suffering of a negative reception on SO.

Consider using a [dedicated Stack Overflow clone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) instead.

Answer (score 3):

If the questions are on topic, and otherwise meet all of the other criteria for good questions on this site, then they are of course welcome.  You are free to direct users to this site for their questions, however you should do so carefully in such a way that they are aware that SO is an entirely separate entity and that there is no affiliation or official agreement between your company and SO, you should direct them to use the appropriate tag, and ensure that they are aware that the site has strict standards for asking questions.  Linking them to the help center, possibly to [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good idea.

As for the tag, if there are existing questions that it would apply to, you can usually just comment on one of them and a high rep user can create/add the relevant tag.  If you can't get enough traffic to do that, you can flag the question or post on meta with the specific question that the tag applies to, and possibly a short description of why the tag is needed.